# GHC Overlapping instances when generalising addition

Tags: haskell, typeclass, overlapping-instances

Trying to generalise `(+)` to more than just `Num`s, I wrote a up an `Addable` class:

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}

class Addable a where
  (+) :: Addable a => a -> a -> a

instance Addable [a] where
  (+) = (++)

instance Num a => Addable a where
  (+) = (Prelude.+)
```

When trying to add (concatenate) lists, GHC complains about overlapping instances:

```
*Test> "abc" + "defghi"

<interactive>:84:7:
    Overlapping instances for Addable [Char] arising from a use of `+'
    Matching instances:
      instance Num a => Addable a -- Defined at Utils.hs:23:10
      instance Addable [a] -- Defined at Utils.hs:20:10
    In the expression: "abc" + "defghi"
    In an equation for `it': it = "abc" + "defghi"
```

I know that GHC disregards context when choosing instances of typeclasses, so trying to choose between `Addable [a]`  and `Addable a` is indeed a problem. However, I expect GHC to choose the first definition since it is more specific. *Why isn't that happening?*

Furthermore, is there an elegant workaround for this problem? Or am I going at this from the wrong angle?

Comment: [That class already exists](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html) as of GHC8, by the way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to enable overlapping instances in order to actually *use* them. In older versions of the compiler, you could do this per-module with the `OverlappingInstances` extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}
```

This works properly for this code:

```
λ> :set -XOverlappingInstances
λ> "abc" + "def"
"abcdef"
```

However, this approach is deprecated in newer versions of GHC (at least in 8.0):

```
Misc.hs:1:73-92: warning: …
    -XOverlappingInstances is deprecated: 
      instead use per-instance pragmas OVERLAPPING/OVERLAPPABLE/OVERLAPS
```

So the more modern approach is to specify this on a per-instance basis:

```
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Num a => Addable a where
  (+) = (Prelude.+)
```

This style of pragma also exists for `OVERLAPPING`, `OVERLAPS` and `INCOHERENT`, letting you annotate specific instances with these properties.

Comment: I'll just sit here and facepalm myself using all hands available. How did I not see this?

Comment: @ThreeFx: I figured out how to use the per-instance pragma. Also, I've run into this problem myself—it's weird to need an extension when I *use* an instance rather than when I define it!