# generic-sop and lists, Data.Proxy etc

Tags: haskell

In the spirit of the question I asked here, [(Generically) Build Parsers from custom data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42583838/generically-build-parsers-from-custom-data-types) 
@danidiaz supplied a solution that works beautifully.

I'd like to do a little more like this: if `f` is an instance of a `HasParser`, a list of `f` is also an instance of the `HasParser`. Or in Haskell, that is

```
instance (HasParser f) => HasParser [f] where
  getParser = many' (getParser @f)
```

Well, this would not compile. I get the following error message:

> error: Not in scope: type variable ‘f’

I am unfamiliar with the syntax with these language extensions. In particular, the usage of `@` with `Proxy` always confuses me a lot. Hope some one can show me where to find the best documentation to read.

Comment: You realise that this is a [type application](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/TypeApplication) (which doesn't work at all prior to GHC-8.0)?

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. I am using ghc 8.0.2 to compile the code.

Answer (score 2):

You need `ScopedTypeVariables` for this.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScoperTypeVariables, UnicodeSyntax #-}

instance ∀ f . HasParser f => HasParser [f] where
  getParser = many' (getParser @f)
```

(ASCII syntax `instance forall f . HasParser ...` also works.)

Comment: It is funny. with `forall f . ` the code failed to compile. But my code compiled as-is with turning on `ScopedTypeVariables` language extension.

Comment: Well a catch! The code compiles as long as no `data` has a `String` filed. Otherwise, the compiler complaints about  "Overlapping instances for HasParser [Char]". This is confusing me, as I don't have `Char` as an instance of `HasParser`. See the code at https://pastebin.com/FYrQHa5w  . Code works fine without the `String` part.

Comment: @user2812201 I believe the overlapping problem is caused by the `HasParser String` instance. In Haskell, strings are really lists of chars. Is switching to something like `Text` possible? If not, perhaps something like an OVERLAPPABLE pragma could work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39215103/ghc-overlapping-instances-when-generalising-addition

Comment: @danidiaz I believe the problem is caused by the `HasParser String` instance too. I'm trying to understand the reason, though: I don't have `instance HasParser Char` anywhere in the code, but GHC seems to think `Char` is an instance of `HasParser`, why?

Comment: @user2812201 The problem is really the instance for `String`. GHC sees that there are two possible definitions it can use: the basic instance for `String` and the one you have defined for lists, and it can't choose. You can nudge him trough a OVERLAPPABLE pragma in the more general instance or an OVERLAPPING pragma in your more specific instance, the one for `String`.

Comment: @danidiaz Sorry for too many questions but I'm really trying to understand this issue here. Let's look at the second way to instantiate `String`: as an list of `Char`s. Does not this require `Char` to be an instance of `HasParser` in the first place? Is GHC making `Char` an instance of `HasParser` automatically?

Comment: @user2812201 This is because the way instance resolution works, which is less "smart" than commonly assumed. When selecting which instance to use, *only the instance head* is checked, *not* the preconditions! If *after* having commited to an instance the preconditions (`HasParser Char` in this case) can't be met, compilation simply fails. GHC doesn't use the absence of a precondition to reject potential instances or resolve an ambiguity.